# codeigniter foreach multiple entries with same ID

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

i try to show users in a specific team. My problem is, that i can show all users, but not only this with a specific team_id. If i view my site domain.com/teams/1 i want to see only users from team_id 1

Maybe you can help me, what i need to change on this line

```
$data['users'] = $this->db->get('users')->result();
```

that i only get users from the users team_id.

I have two sql tables

table users

```
user_id username team_id

   1     paul      1
   2     tom       2
   3     brad      1
   4     pim       2
```

table team

```
team_id   teamname

  1         team1
  2         team1
```

now i try to view paul and brad as team one and tom and pim as team 2.

controller

```
public function index($id) {
        $data = array();
         if ($id) {
            $this->{$this->model}->{$this->_primary_key} = $id;
            $this->{$this->model}->order_by['teams_id'] = 'DESC';


            $data['users'] = $this->db->get('users')->result();


            $data['item'] = $this->{$this->model}->get();
            $this->load->view($this->module, $data); 
            if (!$data['item'])
                show_404();
         }

    }
```

view domain.com/teams/1

```
<?php foreach ($users as $item): ?>
     <?php echo $item->username ?>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call where before get:

```
$this->db->where('team_id', $id);
$data['users'] = $this->db->get('users')->result();
```

Answer (score 0):

public function index($team_id=0)
 {

```
 $data=array();
 if($team_id > 0)
 {
    $data['team_users'] = $this->Team_modal->getTeamUsers($team_id);
 }

  $this->load->view('showTeam',$data);

  /*

  if you want to print data then :
  if(count($data['team_users']) > 0){
          foreach($data['team_users'] as $row){
             echo"user_id =".$row['user_id']."  username =".$row['username']."  team_id =".$row['team_id']."<br>";
          }
      }
      else{
        echo"Oops no data for rquested team id..";
      }
  */
```

}

In Model :

public function getTeamUsers($team_id)
{

```
$this->db->select('user_id,username,team_id');
$this->db->where('team_id',$team_id);
return $this->db->get('table_name')->result_array();
```

}